# play framework 2.10 auto-test

Tags: playframework-2.0

I've seen that there is/was a `play auto-test` command. However, my play 2.10 version doesn't show it on `play help` and it doesn't work. But I can't find any information of it being removed.

Is this command still available or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [the doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/PlayConsole), you can use `~ test` in your Play console to continuously test your project each time you modify a source file.